# How to read SalesForce IdP SAML Assertion in Custom Controller

Tags: controller-extension, saml

in our implementation. I need a way for my custom APEX codes and controller to be able to retrieve the SAML assertion generated from the SFDC platform (IdP).  So I can pass the assertion to the external Web API and get the token back. Any advice woud be highly appreciated.